# Webbrowser Auto login, no id/name of inputbox

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, authentication, c#-4.0

I need to auto login to a website (https://kite.zerodha.com/) using WebBrowser control in VB.NET but  the problem is input field doesn't have any id/name in order to search element and set a value, this is what it shows when i use inspect element on that input text field.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="User ID" autocorrect="off" maxlength="6" autofocus="autofocus" autocapitalize="characters" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8"> event
```

[Update]
I have tried below code and able to set the value, but when i invoke method (submit button) both input gets empty.

```vb
        Dim ele As HtmlElement
        ele = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")(0)
        ele.SetAttribute("value", "test")
        ele = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")(1)
        ele.SetAttribute("value", "test")
```

[Update 2]

This code helped me to insert text into the textboxes.

```html
    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("input")(0).SetAttribute("innertext", "username")
    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("input")(0).SetAttribute("value", "username")
    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("input")(1).SetAttribute("innertext", "password")
    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("input")(1).SetAttribute("value", "password")
```

Comment: You should post the URI of the Web Form you're trying to fill in. Btw, why are you enumerating `DIV` elements when you need the `INPUT` elements?

Comment: Based on the HTML code you've shown us you can use the `placeholder` attribute to find the element, e.g. `If elem2.GetAttribute("placeholder") = "User ID" Then` (though for this to work you have to `GetElementsByTagName("input")` instead).

Comment: Thanks, i tried using other code and able to set the value but when i click submit both input automatically gets empty

Comment: `ele.InnerText = "TestID1"` and `ele.SetAttribute("value", "Password")`. Then `Dim buttonElm = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON").OfType(Of HtmlElement)().FirstOrDefault() If buttonElm isnot nothing then buttonElm.InvokeMember("click") end if`. This code must be inserted in the `DocumentCompleted` event, after the usual check: `If webBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete then return`

Comment: Thanks Jimi, values are inserted on both input elements but when i click on password this field becomes empty, also i tried using the same way like user input ele.innertext = "password" but no luck. because when i click on submit button it says password should be minimum 6 character, that means input box is not having a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a closer look at the WebForm login structure:

- The HTML Input and Submit Elements implement an event that generates an animation.
- The elements have an attached dynamic redefinition of both the `<INPUT>` and `<BUTTON><SUBMIT>` internal html (the Elements' attributes are modified *on the fly*).

This means that we have to:

- Set both the **`InnerText`** and the **`value`** Attribute of the `HtmlElement`
- Use the [IHTMLScriptElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768904(v%3Dvs.85)) interface's [`event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768900%28v%3Dvs.85%29) and [`readystate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh870547) properties to determine when the animation has ended **OR** defer the execution of **`HtmlElement.SetAttribute`** and **`HtmlElement.InvokeMember`**.

Since we need to add a reference to the `mshtml` COM library to implement the `IHTMLScriptElement` interface, here I'm opting for the deferred excution method: it just needs an async Task.

I'm using a **`Dictionary(Of Uri, String)`** to store the Login addresses and the corresponding UserId/Password pairs. This collection is then parsed to determine, in the [DocumentCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) event,  whether the current **`WebBrowser.Url`** requires a Login procedure.
If this is the case - and also the [WebBrowser.Document.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.forms) collection is not empty (there's actually a Form to fill in) - the Async **`DoWebFormLogin`** function is called, passing the UserID and Password required to perform the Login.

```vb
Dim loginAddresses As New Dictionary(Of Uri, String)() From {
    {New Uri("https://kite.zerodha.com"), "testId|TestPassword1"},
    {New Uri("https://www.someothersite.com/login") "user@domain.com|ThePassword1"}
}

Private Async Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
    If wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete OrElse wb.Document.Forms.Count = 0 Then Return
    Dim values As String = String.Empty
    If loginAddresses.TryGetValue(wb.Url, values) Then
        Dim usrPwd = values.Split("|"c)
        Await DoWebFormLogin(wb, usrPwd(0), usrPwd(1))
    End If
End Sub

Private Async Function DoWebFormLogin(wb As WebBrowser, usrId As String, pwd As String) As Task
    Dim userIDSet As Boolean = False
    Dim passwordSet As Boolean = False
    Dim inputElms = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").OfType(Of HtmlElement)().ToList()
    If inputElms.Count < 2 Then
        Return
    End If
    For Each elm As HtmlElement In inputElms
        If elm.GetAttribute("type").Equals("text") Then
            elm.Focus()
            Await Task.Delay(50)
            elm.InnerText = usrId
            elm.SetAttribute("value", usrId)
            userIDSet = True
        End If
        If elm.GetAttribute("type").Equals("password") Then
            elm.Focus()
            Await Task.Delay(50)
            elm.InnerText = pwd
            elm.SetAttribute("value", pwd)
            passwordSet = True
        End If

        If userIDSet AndAlso passwordSet Then
            Dim buttonElms = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON").OfType(Of HtmlElement)().ToList()
            For Each button As HtmlElement In buttonElms
                If button.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") Then
                    button.Focus()
                    Await Task.Delay(50)
                    button.InvokeMember("click")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

C# version of the same procedure, since you're tagging both languages:

```
Dictionary<Uri, string> loginAddresses = new Dictionary<Uri, string>()
{
    { new Uri("https://kite.zerodha.com"), "testId|TestPassword1" },
    { new Uri("https://www.someothersite.com/login") "user@domain.com|ThePassword1" }
};

private async void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var wb = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete || wb.Document.Forms.Count == 0) return;
    if (loginAddresses.TryGetValue(wb.Url, out string values)) {
        var usrPwd = values.Split('|');
        await DoWebFormLogin(wb, usrPwd[0], usrPwd[1]);
    }
}

private async Task DoWebFormLogin(WebBrowser wb, string usrId, string pwd)
{
    bool userIDSet = false;
    bool passwordSet = false;
    var inputElms = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").OfType<HtmlElement>().ToList();
    if (inputElms.Count < 2) return;
    foreach (var elm in inputElms)
    {
        if (elm.GetAttribute("type").Equals("text")) {
            elm.Focus();
            await Task.Delay(50);
            elm.InnerText = usrId;
            elm.SetAttribute("value", usrId);
            userIDSet = true;
        }
        if (elm.GetAttribute("type").Equals("password")) {
            elm.Focus();
            await Task.Delay(50);
            elm.InnerText = pwd;
            elm.SetAttribute("value", pwd);
            passwordSet = true;
        }

        if (userIDSet && passwordSet) {
            var buttonElms = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON").OfType<HtmlElement>().ToList();
            foreach (var button in buttonElms) {
                if (button.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit")) {
                    button.Focus();
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                    button.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I don't know why the conditions were not satisfying to  enter into the if condition DoWebFormLogin(wb, usrPwd(0), usrPwd(1), I tried debug all the conditions even sorted out but still it was not working, however i got the clue from your code to know how can i insert text in the fileds.